# Not understanding the error I'm getting in my array

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and hope people can help me get a better insight. I'm trying to resolve a problem I did in JS into PHP to better understand the syntax and am running to this error:

PHP fatal error: uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Serializer::serializeArray() must be of type array, null given, called in /leetcode/precomiled/serializer.php

This is my code. I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong to better understand and avoid further PHP mistakes. Thank you to all who answer.

```
class Solution {
    function twoSum($nums, $target) {
        $collection = array();

        foreach($nums as $key => $num) {
            $subtracted = $target - $num;

            if ($collection[$subtracted]) {
                return array($collection[$subtracted], $key);  
            } else {
                $collection[$num] = $key;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure where Serializer::serializeArray() is happening (not in this code), but it's probably because your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: A PHP function implicitly returns null if you don't tell it to return something, and there are some possible paths through your function where nothing will be returned.

Comment: If the `foreach` loop finishes without ever finding `$collection[$subtracted]`, the function won't return anything.

Comment: @Steven, what is the function actually supposed to do? I think I can sort of tell from context, but not sure

Comment: `$key->$num` looks like a typo for `$key => $num`. I assume it's a copying error or you'd get other errors.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The function suppose to find the two index values that when added will produce the target. So if the array has [2,7,11,15] and target was 9 then it'll return [0, 1]

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I updated the minor syntax error I had.

Comment: What is it supposed to return if it can't find any values that fit the criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function doesn't work correctly when the pair of numbers includes the first element of the array. You use:

```
if ($collection[$subtracted])
```

to test if `$subtracted` is a key of the array. But if the value of `$collection[$subtracted]` is `0`, that will also fail the `if` test. Change that to:

```
if (isset($collection[$subtracted]))
```

You should also add:

```
return array();
```

after the `for` loop, so that it returns an empty array by default if no matching elements are found.

```
function twoSum($nums, $target) {
    $collection = array();

    foreach($nums as $key => $num) {
        $subtracted = $target - $num;

        if (isset($collection[$subtracted])) {
            return array($collection[$subtracted], $key);  
        } else {
            $collection[$num] = $key;
        }
    }

    return array();
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. It was producing a 0 index which caused that error. Thank you. I'll need to research what isset is in order to better use that function for the future.